# Is it possible to enable EnableEnhancedMonitoring for AWS Kinesis via CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

We would like to log enhanced (per shard) metrics for kinesis using CDK. For standard metrics we're doing this:

```js
  const throughput = new cloudwatch.GraphWidget({
    height: CHART_HEIGHT,
    width: CHART_WIDTH,
    title: "Throughput Exceptions",
  });
  throughput.addLeftMetric(
    stream.metric("ReadProvisionedThroughputExceeded", { statistic: "avg" })
  );
```

Could not find an obvious way to do it for enhanced metrics from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_kinesis-readme.html), but perhaps I missed something.

Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using an AWSCustomResource. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450310/how-to-add-enhanced-shard-level-metrics-on-aws-kinesis-via-cdk/74452274#74452274

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I can tell. I've pulled down the CDK for aws-kinesis and modified the constructs to do what I want. Ideally you don't have to do this, however sometimes the less supported services like kinesis require this. [cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-cloudwatch-readme.html) allows you to specify other ones that are not out of the box with cdk. That's the simpler solution if you're not planning to modify the construct and own that code.

TL;DR

- make the SDK call to [enable it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_EnableEnhancedMonitoring.html) and the appropriate [sdk call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html#enableEnhancedMonitoring-property)

```
var params = {
  ShardLevelMetrics: [ /* required */
    IncomingBytes | IncomingRecords | OutgoingBytes | OutgoingRecords | WriteProvisionedThroughputExceeded | ReadProvisionedThroughputExceeded | IteratorAgeMilliseconds | ALL,
    /* more items */
  ],
  StreamName: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
kinesis.enableEnhancedMonitoring(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

run that lambda [once](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10820)

- or modify the [construct](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-kinesis/lib/kinesis-fixed-canned-metrics.ts) if you're super keen. That's assuming [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesis-stream.html) allows it which doesn't appear to be the case.