# How to add Enhanced (shard-level) metrics on AWS Kinesis via CDK?

Tags: terraform, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis

I'm converting how I build resources from terraform to CDK and I've come across an issue involving adding shard-level metrics to a kinesis stream construct.

I've searched several resources (CDK documentation, Github, stackoverflow) and haven't found any examples or much documentation on adding shard-level metrics to a kinesis stream construct.

Terraform allows you add it by passing them through shard_level_metrics:

```
resource "aws_kinesis_stream" "test_stream" {
  name             = "terraform-kinesis-test"
  shard_count      = 1
  retention_period = 48

  // HERE
  shard_level_metrics = [
    "IncomingBytes",
    "OutgoingBytes",
  ]

  stream_mode_details {
    stream_mode = "PROVISIONED"
  }
}
```

I'm not seeing anything similar for CDK.  Can someone please help/guide me in the right direction?

The only other post I found was [Is it possible to enable EnableEnhancedMonitoring for AWS Kinesis via CDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72063041/is-it-possible-to-enable-enableenhancedmonitoring-for-aws-kinesis-via-cdk) but there isn't a selected potential solution involving CDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and reviewing tickets on Github for [cloud formation](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/768) and [cdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/21136), I learned that there is no way to add enhanced (shard-level) metrics using the [AWS Kinesis construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_kinesis-readme.html#metrics).

To solve this problem using CDK, you can implement an [AWSCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html).

It stands up more resources than I wanted but it gets the job done by creating a lambda:

```
const stream = new kinesis.Stream(this, "stream", {
    streamName: "stream",
    shardCount: 1
});

new cr.AwsCustomResource(
  this,
  "EnableEnhancedMonitoring.PinpointStream",
  {
    policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
      resources: [stream.streamArn]
    }),
    onCreate: {
      action: "enableEnhancedMonitoring",
      service: "Kinesis",
      region: "YOUR_REGION",
      physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(
        "Kinesis.EnableEnhancedMonitoring.DesiredShardLevelMetrics"
      ),
      outputPaths: ["DesiredShardLevelMetrics"],
      parameters: {
        ShardLevelMetrics: [
          "IncomingBytes",
          "OutgoingBytes",
          "IncomingRecords",
          "OutgoingRecords"
        ],
        StreamName: stream.streamName
      }
    }
  }
);
```

It adds the 4 shard levels metrics (verified in console under the stream) during the cdk deploy process.